# Why does this neural network model work poorly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a convolutional neural network, but for some reason after training it is absolutely useless.

She always gives such results.
*unknown* (score = 1.00000)
test (score = 0.00000)

Maybe I built the model wrong.

I would like to know. What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```py
def create_conv_model(fingerprint_input, model_settings, is_training):

  if is_training:
    dropout_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_prob')

  weights = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 8])),
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 8, 16])),
    'wc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 16, 16])),
    'wc4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 32])),
    'wc5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 32, 32])),
    'wc6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 32])),
    'wc7': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 32, 32]))
  }

  biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc7': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc8': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))
  }

  fingerprint_input = tf.reshape(fingerprint_input, shape=[-1, 98, 40, 1], name="fingerprint_input")

  conv1 = depthwise_conv2d(fingerprint_input, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])

  pool1 = maxpool2d(conv1, 3)

  conv2 = conv2d(pool1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])

  conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])

  pool2 = maxpool2d(conv3, 3)

  conv4 = conv2d(pool2, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])

  conv5 = conv2d(conv4, weights['wc5'], biases['bc5'])

  conv6 = conv2d(conv5, weights['wc6'], biases['bc6'])

  conv7 = conv2d(conv6, weights['wc7'], biases['bc7'])

  fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv7)

  fc1 = tf.layers.dense(fc1, 2)

  sft = tf.nn.softmax(fc1, name='labels_softmax')

  if is_training:
    return sft, dropout_prob
  else:
    return sft
```

Comment: Could you please confirm what 'tf' is? (tensorflow?)

Comment: @PaulaThomas  import tensorflow as tf

Comment: You have a newborn model. It could do lots of things but it hasn’t been trained. At birth you get crying, and pooping only. It takes input data, training, and an error function to get goo goo or mama out of it.

Comment: @EngrStudent Here the problem is most likely that it does not have a dropout.

Comment: Tell me about error metric and training.

Comment: @EngrStudent For training, I use standard wav files, convert them using a standard tutorial.

Comment: What is the model's loss function, optimizer? Can you please explain about the input dataset, number of classes predicting and also share the model.summary().

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the case of Overfitting. You can

1. `Shuffle` the `Data`, by using `shuffle=True` in `cnn_model.fit`. Code is shown below:

   `history = cnn_model.fit(x = X_train_reshaped,
                           y = y_train,
                           batch_size = 512,
                           epochs = epochs, callbacks=[callback],
                           verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test_reshaped, y_test),
                           validation_steps = 10, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, shuffle = True)`
2. Use `Early Stopping`. Code is shown below

   `callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)`
3. Use Regularization. Code for Regularization is shown below (You can try l1 Regularization or l1_l2 Regularization as well):

`from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2`

`Regularizer = l2(0.001)`

`cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64,3, 3, input_shape = (28,28,1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`

`cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`

4. You can try using `BatchNormalization`.
5. Perform Image Data Augmentation using `ImageDataGenerator`. Refer [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/) for more info about that.
6. If the Pixels are not `Normalized`, Dividing the Pixel Values with `255` also helps.
7. Finally, if there still no change, you can try using `Pre-Trained Models` like `ResNet` or `VGG Net`, etc..

For more information please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061266/how-to-improve-my-cnn-high-and-constant-validation-error/59172613#59172613).