# How to improve my CNN ? high and constant validation error

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, conv-neural-network

I am working on a problem for predicting a score of how fat cows are, based on images of cows. 
I applied a CNN to estimate the value which is between 0-5 ( the dataset i have, contains only values between 2.25 and 4 )
I am using 4 CNN layers and 3 Hidden layers.

I actualy have 2 problems :
1/  I got 0.05 training error, but after 3-5 epochs the validation error remains at about 0.33.
2/  The value predicted by my NN are between 2.9 and 3.3 which is too narrow compared with the dataset range. Is it normal ?

How can i improve my model ?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(512, 424,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(512, 424)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])
```

Learning Curve:

[image: Learning Curve]

Prediction:

[image: Prediction]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be the case of Overfitting. You can

1. `Shuffle` the `Data`, by using `shuffle=True` in `cnn_model.fit`. Code is shown below:

   `history = cnn_model.fit(x = X_train_reshaped,
                           y = y_train,
                           batch_size = 512,
                           epochs = epochs, callbacks=[callback],
                           verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test_reshaped, y_test),
                           validation_steps = 10, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, shuffle = True)`
2. Use `Early Stopping`. Code is shown below

   `callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)`
3. Use Regularization. Code for Regularization is shown below (You can try l1 Regularization or l1_l2 Regularization as well):

`from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2`

`Regularizer = l2(0.001)`

`cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64,3, 3, input_shape = (28,28,1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`

`cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))`

4. You can try using `BatchNormalization`.
5. Perform Image Data Augmentation using `ImageDataGenerator`. Refer [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/) for more info about that.
6. If the Pixels are not `Normalized`, Dividing the Pixel Values with `255` also helps.
7. Finally, if there still no change, you can try using `Pre-Trained Models` like `ResNet` or `VGG Net`, etc..