# Why do CNN's sometimes make highly confident mistakes, and how can one combat this problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I trained a simple CNN on the MNIST database of handwritten digits to 99% accuracy. I'm feeding in a bunch of handwritten digits, and non-digits from a document.

I want the CNN to report errors, so I set a threshold of 90% certainty below which my algorithm assumes that what it's looking at is not a digit.

My problem is that the CNN is 100% certain of many incorrect guesses. In the example below, the CNN reports 100% certainty that it's a 0. How do I make it report failure?

[image]

**My thoughts on this**:
Maybe the CNN is not really 100% certain that this is a zero. Maybe it just thinks that it can't be anything else, and it's being forced to choose (because of normalisation on the output vector). Is there any way I can get insight into what the CNN "thought" before I forced it to choose?

PS: I'm using Keras on Tensorflow with Python.

Comment: I feel this would be more suited for https://ai.stackexchange.com/ (And oh, how I wish I knew the answer..)

Comment: Well I'm thinking about it more. I suppose I could remove the softmax activation function on the final dense layer. Then I'll just get the activations before being normalised. Maybe I can put a threshold on that.
Will post it on ai as well to see if I get bites.

Comment: A network learns whatever mapping will minimize the loss. This is a natural problem almost all networks face and there will always be some set of adversarial examples. Network calibration is currently a hot topic at the moment.

Comment: @iyop45 thanks. At the same time, worth noting that I tried what I suggested in my comment above and it's giving me the extra info I needed

Comment: You can also try replacing softmax with sigmoid which doesn't attempt to normalize the probabilities.

Comment: @ekmcd good one I'll try. I realised my reasoning was flawed though. My method kind of worked but I found it could be wildly wrong. The activation before normalisation also depends on trivial things like the the brightness of the pixels on the input. I found that I'd get high values for big blocks of scribble which took up most of the input size, simply because the sum of pixel values was relatively high (I think that's why).

Comment: @ekmcd If you don't normalize the logits to be valid probabilities, then you break all the assumptions for doing cross-entropy loss at the output. The general classification task is modeled as minimizing the KL divergence between two probability samples (predictions and GT), which acts as a lower bound for the mutual information between the input and the ground truth labels. Although doing gradient descent with sigmoid would probably work, you will be effectively doing KL divergence on an invalid probability measure, which destroys all the information-theoretic guarantees for convergence.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare I should probably add that Bayesian networks attempt to resolve this very problem by modeling uncertainty i.e. modeling the network and gradient descent in a probabilistic framework.

Comment: May be the Network is overfitting and you can try few of the things mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061266/how-to-improve-my-cnn-high-and-constant-validation-error/59172613#59172613. Also we can retrain the model with report failure class(Again we need to have lot of data for this class and also we can use data augmentation technique to generate more data).